# Call in Vue FE returns 406 Not Acceptable and it does not reach the back end

Tags: c#, vue.js

This is my api call in Vue:

```
const getContractAgreement = async (id, filter) => {
  const response = await httpClient.get(`api/credit-products/overdrafts/${id}/contract-agreement`, { params: { ContentType: 'Pdf' } })

  return response.data
}
```

In FE I am calling this url:

`http://localhost:8088/api/credit-products/overdrafts/bacf5631-9b07-42d4-a175-b0577eedbded/contract-agreement?ContentType=ContentType.Pdf`

This is the backend endpoint. It does not even hit it..

```
 [HttpGet("{id}/contract-agreement")]
    [Produces("text/html", "application/pdf", Type = typeof(FileContentResult))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(ValidationErrorResponse))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, Type = typeof(ValidationErrorResponse))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, Type = typeof(ValidationErrorResponse))]
    public async Task<FileContentResult> GetContractAgreementAsync([FromRoute] string id, GetOverdraftContractAgreementRequest request)
    {
        var query = new GetOverdraftContractAgreementQuery(
            id,
            request.ContentType.ToMimeContentType());

        var result = await Mediator.Send(query);
        return File(result.Content, result.MimeContentType);
    }

public class GetOverdraftContractAgreementRequest
{
    public ContentType ContentType { get; set; }
}

public enum ContentType
{
    Html,
    Pdf,
}

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies that a parameter or property should be bound using route-data from
    //     the current request.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class FromRouteAttribute : Attribute, IBindingSourceMetadata, IModelNameProvider
    {
        public FromRouteAttribute();

        public BindingSource BindingSource { get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Returns 406 Not Acceptable. I cannot get around that in any way. How do I get around this error?

Comment: can you add all the backend code for that route?

Comment: I have added all the code necessary. Please advise.

Comment: where is `credit-products/overdrafts` in the back end?